# how can I display and update a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am new to coding and I am trying to code a battleship game in python based on a code academy design.

Almost everything works but the board display... It prints the 1 first time but then it does not update and I don't really know what to do... 
Could someone help me? (Here is my code!:))

```
import random

def board_ini():
    board = []
    for x in range(0,5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
    return board


def random_row(board):
    rr = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
    return rr

def random_col(board):
    rc = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
    return rc



def Battleship():

    print ("\nLet's play Battleship!\n")
    print ("You are going to guess coordinate. You can type integers between 0 and 4.\n")
    print ("You have a total of 4 tries!\n",end ="" "Good luck!!\n")
    theboard = board_ini()
    ship_row = random_row(theboard)
    ship_col = random_col(theboard)
    print(ship_row)
    print(ship_col)#debugging

    for turn in range(1,5):
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))   #let the user try again?
        except Exception as e:
            print (e.args)
        try:
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))   #let the user try again? 
        except Exception as e:
            print (e.args)

        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print ("\nCongratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
            break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):  
                print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")
            elif(theboard[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):   
                print ("You guessed that one already.")
                turn = turn - 1   #would be nice if it did not count as a turn (turn function ?)
            else:
                print ("You missed my battleship!")
                theboard[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"  

            if turn == 4:
                print ("\nDefeat, Game over!!")
                print ("My Ship was in: %s,%s" % (ship_row,ship_col))
        turn += 1
        print ("Turn: %s" % turn) #prints turn 5(it should not)
        theboard #the board is not displaying correctly (should display the coordinate (X) after each turn but here it does not display at all)

def Game():
    i = True
    while i == True:

        Battleship()

        r = input("Do you want to rematch (Y/N)?")
        if r == "Y":
            r.lower()
            " ".join(r)
            i = True
        else:
            i = False
            print ("Thank you! Game over")

Game()
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I've run this code. It looks like it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only printing the board in the `board_ini` function. I think you want to copy the two lines

```
for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))
```

to the end of the for loop in your `Battleship` function (but change `board` to `theboard`). Or even better, put it in its own `print_board` function.

You also have a problem with `turn`. Doing `turn += 1` at the end of the loop body has no effect. The for loop has already "queued up" all the values `turn` should take, and overwrites `turn` with a new one at the start of each iteration.

If you need to change the loop counter during the iteration, you should consider using a while loop instead.